# Can any one explain what the purpose of this "dd" command that writes to /dev/null is?

Tags: linux, dd, null

```
dd if=/dev/sda7 of=/dev/null bs=1024 skip=276892816 count=420 iflag=direct
```

We are having some issues backing up a Linux server. Anyone, please explain to me what this command does in that case.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: What are the issues you're seeing?

Comment: It does not have any output, so the only possible effect is via its exit status. Is this checked or saved anywhere ? Alternatively: does it throw some low-level failure message to a log somewhere ?

Answer (score 3):

> Anyone please explain me what this command does in that case.

The way to find out is to read `man dd`. If you'd done that, you'd have seen that `if` is the in-file, `of` the out-file, `bs` the blocksize, `skip` skips over blocks and starts at a later address, `count` is the number of blocks, and `iflag` allows you to set various flags.

So this is reading 420 blocks from the second partition and copying them to `/dev/null`, which means ignoring them, starting at the skip address.

> We are having some issues backing up a Linux server.

You didn't give any details, so it's impossible to say how this is related to your issues, in particular as this command doesn't do anything except reading.

So one guess is that this is used to verify that a particular range of sectors is readable. As to why this range, I have no idea.

Also, if you've changed the layout of your partitions in any way, it's likely no longer doing whatever it was supposed to do.